# PHP - How can I dynamically export data to excel file (.xls)?

Tags: php, sql

I'm using php. I'd like to know how can I dynamically export data to excel file (.xls). in the query below in entered the fields in the clause Select which i want to see in the excel file.

```
$query = "SELECT f.attendee_id as id1, f.answer as Prenom, l.answer as Nom, c1.answer as choix
         FROM wp_events_answer f
         JOIN wp_events_answer l ON f.attendee_id = l.attendee_id
         JOIN wp_events_answer c1 ON f.attendee_id = c1.attendee_id
         WHERE (f.question_id = 1) AND (l.question_id = 2) AND (c1.question_id = 28);";
```

And i also entered the labels of this fields:

```
$tbl= " <table border='1'>
<tr height='50px'><td WIDTH='50px' align='center'>ID</td><td WIDTH='50px'   align='center'>Prenom</td><td WIDTH='50px'align='center'>Nom</td><td WIDTH='50px' align='center'>Choix 1</td><td WIDTH='50px' align='center'>Choix 2</td></tr>";.;
```

But i'd like that all this became dynamic because the user can create and modify the forms. So if the user add or modify a field the export will only works if this field is also modified in the code (Select clause).

Can you explain me how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a CSV or an XLS file? Your answer to that question makes a big difference.

Comment: csv makes much more sense for exporing like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL code:

```
SELECT f.attendee_id as id1, f.answer as Prenom, l.answer as Nom, c1.answer as choix
    INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
    FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ';'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    FROM wp_events_answer f
     JOIN wp_events_answer l ON f.attendee_id = l.attendee_id
     JOIN wp_events_answer c1 ON f.attendee_id = c1.attendee_id
     WHERE (f.question_id = 1) AND (l.question_id = 2) AND (c1.question_id = 28);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to export to an xls file. Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just write your data in CSV (comma separated) format into response buffer or disk file (later you may allow user to download it or force download).